# jQuery Does Not Run <script> When AJAX $.load() Method Called by Click Event

Tags: html, jquery, linkedin-api, jquery-events

I've been struggling with this for a while and can't figure it out.  Hopefully it's something obvious that I missed.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#clickbox').load('eventpage/clicks.html.php #click2', function () {
    console.log('click2 loaded');
    $(this).hide()
    .fadeIn(3000);

    $('#click2').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        console.log('click2 clicked');  
        $('#bizdev').load('pagewithscripttags.php', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log('#bizdev is loaded, but scripts are not run');
            $('#bizdev').hide();
            console.log('bizdev hidden');
        });                      
        $('#content').hide();
        $('#bizdev').show();
    });
});
```

**When I run this (from an external js file), the file 'pagewithscripttags.php' is loaded into the DOM on the click event, but the scripts are not executed and I can't figure out why. HELP!**

However, when I move the load method into the callback function of the first load, the file is inserted into the DOM and the scripts are run:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#clickbox').load('eventpage/clicks.html.php #click2', function () {
    console.log('click2 loaded');
    $(this).hide()
    .fadeIn(3000);

    $('#bizdev').load('pagewithscripttags.php', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log('#bizdev loaded and scripts are run');
            $('#bizdev').hide();
            console.log('#bizdev hidden');
    }); 

    $('#click2').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        console.log('click2 clicked');  
        $('#content').hide();
        $('#bizdev').show();
    });
});
```

Why do the scripts run as part of the callback function, but not on the click event (which is when I need them to run)?

Here are the contents of pagewithscripts.php:

```
<script>console.log('this script was run');</script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="http://linkedin.com/publicprofileurl" data-format="inline" width='106px' data-related="false"></script>
```

The first script is run and appears on the console.log, but the second is just inserted into the DOM without being run, except when I place the .load() method outside of the click handler.

(I need to load the scripts on the click event because they take several seconds to run (they call the LinkedIn API) and there's freezing/lag when I run them on document ready.)

Comment: If all you want to load is the LinkedIn script couldn't you simply create it immediately (rather than using ajax to fetch it?). Something like: `$('<script type="IN/MemberProfile" ... data-related="false"></script> 
').appendTo(document.body)` instead of: `$('#bizdev').load('pagewithscripttags.php'...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to tell the LinkedIn framework to re-scan the page.

IN.parse(domNode)

This is covered on the JavaScript API reference document on events here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inauth-inevent-and-inui

Answer (score 0):

Load the script datatype
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: I looked at **.getScript()** and using **eval** to run the scripts, but it wouldn't work without rewriting the LinkedIn widget.  Using **.ajax()** with dataType: "script" does not work.  Using **.ajax()** with dataType: "html" gives the same result as using **.load()**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually jQuery '**click()**' function will not handle the 'click' event of dynamic elements, so try [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [**live()**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) functions to make your code working fine, using these functions you can move the click handler code out of the first load() callback.

FYI: Try to replace your `$('#click2').click(function(e) {` code with this `$('#click2').live("click", function(e) {` code.

Note: 'live()' function is deprecated from the jQuery version 1.7 onwards.

If you are not clear to use these functions then just provide your full page source so that I can check and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I have not understood what you are suggesting, but it appears to me that the **.click()** method IS handling the 'click' event because it prevents the default action, successfully outputs to the console.log, and calls the second **.load()** method.  However, the .load() is stripping out SOME of the script blocks instead of running them like it's supposed to.  I agree that **on()** or **delegate()** would allow the handler code to be moved outside the first load() callback, but why would the scripts run differently?